# shell script for opening the different files in a folder in linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Hi everyone this is saikrishna. I need some help in linux shell scripts. I need to open the different types of files like mp3,mp4,jpg...etc and other extensions are existing in the same folder. I had tried "gnome" code for this but it opens only one file i needed to open all the files one after the other.
is it possible in linux.need help for it

Comment: Applications like eog has a `--slide-show` option which you might be interested in. For example `eog --slide-show ~/Pictures` will open all the images with supported extensions in  a slideshow.

Comment: Also, you may follow [\[ this \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297932/25919) thread that I've started with UL.

Answer (score 1):

You can list multiple files using `ls` and then use `while` to open them one by one:

```
ls *.mp3 | while read -r file; do xdg-open "$file"; done
```

see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/365676) answer for more details.

Comment: Don't parse the `ls` output

Comment: @sjsam Any specific reason not to parse?